# uncompress from zlib.h - error - undefined reference to `uncompress_gzip'

Tags: c++, zlib

I have code in which, I have got compressed data and I need to uncompress it.
I am using zlib for this
I have done:

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

in my .cpp file.
Now, when I compile it, I get the error:
undefined reference to `uncompress_gzip'

Do, I need to link with some lib?

Thanks,
sg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to link it to zlib.  Without knowing what compiler you are using, I'll just use GCC:

```
gcc my.cpp -lz
```

Comment: I always accept answers that solve the problem. But at that time, I was not allowed to accept it as I had to wiat for soemtime before accepting it, so I thought I would first let you know.